# Can I get HDR on the 4th gen iPod Touch by upgrading to iOS 4.1?

Tags: ipod-touch, applications, hdr

I got to see the whole keynote at September 1st and assumed that iOS 4.1 would bring HDR to iPod Touch (4th gen) and the iPhone (3Gs and 4).

Today I got my iPod Touch and I don't get it, where's the HDR button? I get that there is no flash (was announced), but HDR Button should be there, right?

Did I wrongly assume that iPod Touch would have HDR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HDR photo is only available on iPhone 4 with iOS 4.1. Also, the rear camera is less then 1MP where iPhone 3 is 5MP.

[iPod Touch's Software Update](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/software-update/) page does not list HDR photo.

Comment: The 4th gen iPod Touch shipped with 4.1 and would not have been included in the software update. But you are correct that it does not have HDR.

Comment: dang! I know the camera, but I really thought that the new iPod Touch would have HDR as well :(

Comment: There's no HDR for iPhone 3GS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and buy [Pro HDR](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pro-hdr/id347104281?mt=8). This works just great on my iPhone 3GS, even though it is slower than the Apple HDR feature.

Comment: the question says iPod Touch 4th generation right? where's 3Gs named?

Comment: @balexandre Just as the iPod touch 4G, the iPhone 3GS also doesn't have the Apple HDR feature (as you can obviously see on your own screenshot). So this was supposed to be a helpful answer so that you can also take HDR pictures with your iPod touch.